# Trying an alternative to Spark broadcast variable because of NullPointerException ONLY in Local mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was using my Spark app in cluster mode and everything went well. Now, I need to do some test in my local installation (on my laptop) and I get NullPointerException in the following line:

```scala
val brdVar = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(rdd.collectAsMap())
```

**EDIT:** This is the full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at learner.LearnCh$.learn(LearnCh.scala:81)
    at learner.Learner.runLearningStage(Learner.scala:166)
    at learner.Learner.run(Learner.scala:29)
    at Driver$.runTask(Driver.scala:26)
    at Driver$.main(Driver.scala:19)
    at Driver.main(Driver.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I was reading a lot, and I couldn't get the answer to my problem (**EDIT:** I'm using `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = ...`). The use case for this `brdVar` is to get a numerical id value from a string one:

```scala
val newRdd: RDD[(Long, Map[Byte, Int])] = origRdd.mapPartitions { partition => partition.map(r => (r.idString, r)) }
      .aggregateByKey // this line doesn't affect to my problem ....
      .mapPartitions { partition => partition.map { case (idString, listIndexes) => (brdVar.value(idString), .....) } }
```

So, in order to continue and don't get stuck with broadcast in local mode, I change the idea and I wanted to `simulate` the brdVar saving its data in a file, and reading and searching the key calling a function instead of this part `brdVar.value(idString)` doing this  `getNumericalID(id)`. To do so, I've written this function:

```scala
    def getNumericalID(strID: String): Long = {
        val pathToRead = ....

        val file = spark.sparkContext.textFile(pathToRead)
        val process = file.map{line =>
          val l = line.split(",")
          (l(0), l(1))
        }.filter(e=>e._1 == strID).collect()
       process(0)._2.toLong
    }
```

But I'm still getting `NullPointerException` message, but this time in this `val file = ....` line. I've checked, and the file has content. I think maybe I'm misunderstanding something, any ideas?

Comment: can you edit to post the full stacktrace ?

Comment: How does your main method declaration look like? I had similar problems when declared the main class as `object MyClass extends App`. It doesn't work well in Spark. Main class must be specified in java style using `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = ...`

Comment: @EnzoBnl I've just added it.

Comment: @simpadjo yes, I'm using as java style